# How can I hide the label saying "URL*" from content creation form when using the link module?

Tags: entities

I'm using the link module to ask the user for a link. I have disabled the link text (I.E> the text that would be inside the anchor tag) so the user wouldn't be asked for a title. What I would expect to happen is that I wouldn't see the field label, followed by the label "URL*". However, it isn't so.

As an example, my field label is `Download link`. What I see in the node creation form is a label like `Download link*` and then another label with the text `URL*`. Is there a way to hide the latter (the one saying `URL*`)?

Comment: Is this on the node/12 page that you are seeing this? If so you can go to admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/display and tell it whether or not your want labels displayed.

Comment: No, it is on the node creation form – I revised the question to point this out more clearly.

Comment: So you are getting Your label plus the "URL" default label? If this is your problem I don't believe you can fix that via the frontend configuration. You could hide it with CSS though. However, having the word URL there shouldn't really confuse anyone.

Comment: Yeah, that is my problem, since I"m not sure how much my users (they are screen reader users) can handle this. Is there a way to do this through some PHP code? I know PHP much more than Drupal. :-)

Comment: You could with php but it would still be using Drupal hook system. Do you have experience using the Drupal hooks? You could accomplish this using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Comment: If you don't know how to make a module I can help you out.

Comment: That's a great hint right there. Can you make this an answer so that I can accept it to add to your reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change the title of that field to an empty string.

Let me know if you need help along the way.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Manage Display` tab of your content type. On that page you can set how the label is displayed:

- Above
- Inline
- Hidden

and how your link displays:

- Title, as link (default)
- Title, as plain text
- URL, as link
- URL, as plain text
- URL, absolute
- Domain, as link
- Short, as link with title "Link"
- Label, as link with label as title
- Separate title and URL
- Hidden

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the node or content creation form; the one I get shown when I click on "Add new content". I've revised my question to make explicit mention to this fact.